# How to use strcmp in if statement to compare

Tags: c, configuration, strcmp

I am trying to create a C program that reads data from a .ini file. The data is read into a variable named buffer. The data in the .ini file looks like this:

```
 [key]
 title= A, H, D, F
```

My program looks like this:

```
 LPCSTR ini = "C:\\conf.ini";
 char var[100];
 GetPrivateProfileString("key", "title", 0, var, 100, ini);
 char* buffer = strtok(var, ",");
 printf("The complete line is %s", var);

 buffer=strtok(NULL, ",");
 printf(buffer);

 while((buffer= strtok(NULL, ","))!=NULL)
     printf(buffer);
```

The output looks something like this:

```
The complete line is A, H, D, F
A
H
D
F
```

Now here what I want to do is compare each letter received in the 'buffer' to character 'A' and if it is true print Yes, else print No. I have tried using strcmp to compare but the .exe file stopped running.

```
if (strcmp(buffer, "A")==0)
    printf("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fixes I made to your code:

- I put `strcmp()` checking inside the loop so that all pieces of string extracted from `strtok()` will be checked for equality with `"A"`.

  The first string before the delimiter is extracted to `buffer`, then it continues extracting from `buffer` until `NULL` inside the `do-while` loop.
- Since your `ini` file's value has this format of space-after comma (`", "`), I changed the delimiter from `","` to `", "` *(adding space after comma)*.

  Although it won't make much impact in checking for equality with `"A"` since `A` won't be affected *(because it is on the first part of the value* `A, H, D, F`), checking the values of letters in-between commas and space *(such as `H`, `D`, `F`)* will be affected if we will use `","` *(comma only)* as delimiter.

***Modified Code***

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <windows.h>

 int main() {

       LPCSTR ini = "C:\\conf.ini";
       char var[100];
       GetPrivateProfileString("key", "title", NULL, var, sizeof var, ini);
       
       printf("The complete line is %s\n", var);
      
       // first piece of string (letter) before delimiter
       // changed delimiter from "," to ", "
       char* buffer = strtok(var, ", ");
       
       // exits if buffer is NULL
       if ( !buffer )
           return;

       do {  
           // prints the letter
           printf("%s", buffer);
           
           // checking if the extracted piece of code from var is equal with "A",  
           // prints either " Yes" or " No"
           ( !strcmp(buffer, "A") ) ? puts(" Yes") : puts(" No");

       // continues checking until NULL
       } while( buffer = strtok(NULL, ", ") );
 }
```

***Output***

```
The complete line is A, H, D, F
A Yes
H No
D No
F No
```

Answer (score 1):

As from your input format, there are spaces present and you're not considering that as a prt of delimiter. So, expectedly, those spaces will be present in the string pointed bu `buffer`. You can either do

- Change your delimiter to `" ,"`
- Write `if (strcmp(buffer, " A")==0)` and so on.

That said,

1. `printf(buffer);` is a bad style. Either use `puts(buffer)` ot prefer `printf("%s", buffer)`.
2. Check for the `NULL` return from `strtok()` before using that returned pointer.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the style. I forgot to correct the printf statement. But I still dont get it how do I compare the contents of the buffer and then print a statement using if. Could you maybe post a small example code? Thanks for the help anyways!